# JavaScript recursion returning a promise never resolving

Tags: javascript, recursion, async-await

In JavaScript, I have an array of objects being some tasks to do. I iterate through this array with a `for` loop with `await`, calling a function `doOneTask` with returns a `Promise`.

That works pretty well as long as the code inside `doOneTask` works as expected. However, those things often fail. Trying again helps almost all the time. So, I'd like to implement a procedure for auto-retrying inside the JavaScript code.
My idea was a recursive function: In case of a failure, `doOneTask` call itself till the promise if finally resolved.

My code looks like this:

```
var tasks = [{label: 'task0'},{label: 'task1'},{label: 'task2'}];
async function mainFunction() {
    for(let k = 0; k < tasks.length; k++) {
        await doOneTask(tasks[k]);
        console.log("doOneTask done for index " + k);
    }
    console.log("End reached!");
}

function doOneTask(task) {        
    return new Promise(async function (resolve,reject) {    
       console.log("Starting with: " + task.label);            
       let checkIfDoeSomeStuffWorked = await doSomeAsyncStuff();           
       if(checkIfDoeSomeStuffWorked == false) {
           console.log(task.label + ": FAILED");
           return doOneTask(task);
       }
       else {
           console.log(task.label + ": SUCCESS");
           resolve(true);
       }
    }); 
}

function doSomeAsyncStuff() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve,reject) {        
        var myRandom = Math.random();        
        if(myRandom < 0.3) {
            resolve(true);
        }
        else {
            resolve(false);
        }        
    });
}

mainFunction();
```

(In real life, `doSomeAsyncStuff` is a backend call which often fails. The `random()` part is just for demonstration. In reality, I also limit the number of trials, before stopping the script.)

However, it doesn't work. In case of a failure, the script stops after having reached the `SUCCESS` console log. I never get back to the loop and the next items in the loop never get executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having completed the question, but just before posting, something came into my mind: In the setup above, I don't resolve the very same promise object when I finally reach success, but for each function call a new promise object is generated. My solution/workaround is quite simple: use `q` the promise library passing the promise from one function call to the next function call:

```
var q = require('q');
async function doOneTask(task,promiseObj) {

    if(!promiseObj) {
        var promiseObj = q.defer();
    }

    console.log("Starting with: " + task.label); 

    let checkIfDoeSomeStuffWorked = await doSomeAsyncStuff();

    if(checkIfDoeSomeStuffWorked == false) {
           console.log(task.label + ": FAILED");
           return doOneTask(task,promiseObj);
    }
    else {
           console.log(task.label + ": SUCCESS");
           promiseObj.resolve(true);
       }

    return promiseObj.promise;
}
```

That way, we make sure that the very same `promise` object which is generated at the first call of `doOneTask` is resolved in the end - event after the 20th execution.

Answer (score 1):

You have no use for the `q` library dependency. `async` functions always return a Promise, so you can simplify your code quite a bit -

```
async function doOneTask (task) {
  const result = await doSomeAsyncStuff()
  if (result === false) {
    console.log(`${task} failed`)
    return doOneTask(task)
  }
  else {
    console.log(`${task} passed`)
    return true
  }
}
```

Your fake function `doSomeAsyncStuff` can be cleaned up too -

```
async function doSomeAsyncStuff () {
  return Math.random() < 0.3
}
```

But let's add a fake delay of 1 second so that we can show things working 100% -

```
async function doSomeAsyncStuff () {
  return new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000, Math.random() < 0.3)
  )
}
```

Last, your `main` function uses a really old looping convention. As you're using modern JavaScript, you might as well use `for-of` syntax -

```
async function main (tasks = []) {
  for (const t of tasks) {
    await doOneTask(t)
  }
  return "done"
}
```

Finally we run the program -

```
const tasks =
  [ 'task0', 'task1', 'task2' ]

main(tasks).then(console.log, console.error)
// task0 failed
// task0 passed
// task1 failed
// task1 failed
// task1 passed
// task2 passed
// done
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the results in your own browser -

```js
async function doOneTask (task) {
  const result = await doSomeAsyncStuff()
  if (result === false) {
    console.log(`${task} failed`)
    return doOneTask(task)
  }
  else {
    console.log(`${task} passed`)
    return true
  }
}

async function doSomeAsyncStuff () {
  return new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000, Math.random() < 0.3)
  )
}

async function main (tasks = []) {
  for (const t of tasks) {
    await doOneTask(t)
  }
  return "done"
}

const tasks =
  [ 'task0', 'task1', 'task2' ]

main(tasks).then(console.log, console.error)
// task0 failed
// task0 passed
// task1 failed
// task1 failed
// task1 passed
// task2 passed
// done
```